# Run Unix-based executable file on the same system

Tags: c, macos, unix, terminal

I created a Tic Tac Toe C program on the Eclipse IDE for Mac. Then, when I wanted to run the file on terminal, I wrote the file on VIM and when I ran it worked perfectly. However, the problem I'm having is, when I sent that same executable (I uploaded it to Mediafire and then had them download it) program to many friends who own a Mac with obviously a UNIX-based OS as well, the program never worked. Instead of an executable file, it became a document. What's the reason for that and how do I make my program work on other Unix-based OS's?

Comment: Note that your executable will not run on Unix platforms other than OS X. OS X binaries are stored in Mach-O format, while most unixes use ELF (or a.out or COFF or...) instead (see [this Wikipedia article](http://www.netbsd.org/docs/compat.html)). And even if the file formats were the same, there are likely to be differences in the ABI ([things like calling conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface)) that'd make the executable nonportable. In general, you'll have to recompile your program for each platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your friends should mark the program as executable by giving it the "execute" permission. When you upload a file to a server on the Internet all of its attributes like permissions and timestamps are lost.

Another option is uploading the file packed in an archive format that does save attributes. One such option is `tar`. To create a compressed tar file containing `program` you can use:

```
tar czf program.tar.gz program
```

Comment: Can you give me some more insight on the tar method?

Comment: The command to create such a file is included in the answer, what more do you want to know? It can be decompressed on OS X by double clicking if I recall correctly.

Comment: I'm sorry, I got it, thank you for the future insight and help.